# awk - cross match columns across another file and replace fields

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a stdout:

```
jh888636 4533 cklsls 55885
sp838922 7373 ksshhs 77321
dp828273 8722 kiwjkk 72661
```

and  a static file to lookup:

```
"ah768889"|"Aron Hease"|"Louis Jid"|"99949"
"jh888636"|"John Holmes"|"Peter King"|"60036"
"sp838922"|"Steven Parn"|"Jay Walker"|"60004"
"dp828273"|"David Pim"|"Kate Jast"|"89488"
```

Now, my goal is to match column 1 from stdout to column 1 in the static file and extract/print column2/column4 etc

Exampled desired output:

```
John Holmes (60036) 4533 cklsls 55885
Steven Parn (60004) 7373 ksshhs 77321
David Pim   (89488)  8722 kiwjkk 72661
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `awk` approach:

```
... |awk 'NR==FNR{one=$1;$1="";seen[one]=$0; next} 
{FS="[|\"]"} seen[$2]{printf ("%s (%s) %s\n", $5, $(NF-1), seen[$2])}' - static
```

Will give output:

```
John Holmes (60036)  4533 cklsls 55885
Steven Parn (60004)  7373 ksshhs 77321
David Pim (89488)  8722 kiwjkk 72661
```

At above in `- static`; the dash `-` means *awk* to read from stdin and the `static` is your *staticfile*.

Answer (score -1):

I have done this by 4 steps

1. `sed "s/|/ /g" staticfile_lookup | sed 's/"//g'  >> static_file_lookup_final.txt`

   2. `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}($1 in a){print $2,$3,$NF}' stdout  static_file_lookup_final.txt  >>static_file_lookup_fina1_1.txt`
2. `awk '{$1="";print $0}' stdout  >>stdout_final.txt`

==========

```
cat static_file_lookup_fina1_1.txt 
John Holmes 60036
Steven Parn 60004
David Pim 89488
```

============

```
 cat stdout_final.txt 
 4533 cklsls 55885
 7373 ksshhs 77321
 8722 kiwjkk 72661
```

=================

4. `paste static_file_lookup_fina1_1.txt stdout_final.txt`

Output

```
John Holmes 60036    4533 cklsls 55885
Steven Parn 60004    7373 ksshhs 77321
David Pim 89488  8722 kiwjkk 72661
```

Comment: -1 You are replacing Pipes with Space `sed "s/|/ /g"` and printing `$2,$3,$NF`. What  if names in second column (separated with pipe) has no space or has  middle name? + no `(...)` is formatted. you could do all with single `awk`